# Using Themes with URL rewriting in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using the UrlRewriter.NET library to perform URL rewriting. I noticed that themes do not work properly as the browser tries to retrieve the CSS file incorrectly.

The link tag generated by ASP.NET automatically is as follows:

```
<link href="App_Themes/vertebrata/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

URL typed into browser: localhost:1708/BloggingEngine/aa
Displays fine

URL typed into browser: localhost:1708/BloggingEngine/aa/
Browser does not load the CSS file

I can probably fix the problem by prefixing a "/" before the URL in the href attribute, but this is dynamically generated by ASP.net depending on selected theme and I have no control over it.

How do I get ASP.net to load themes properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question but a pointer to URL rewriting -

Now I haven't investigated the issue at all, and there may be a simple fix - as you have suggested.  However, you , may find the following article interesting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems displaying my logo and after many nights looking for a solution.  I found a partial solution here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/using-an-Asp-Net-master-page-with-theme-and-css/

First of all, I resolved my css theme by adding Pager.Resolve...
    " type="text/css" />

Secondly, I resolved my ImageUrl by adding Page.ResolveUrl....

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HeaderLink" 
                                   ImageUrl='<%# Page.ResolveUrl( "~/Images/BalloonShopLogo.png" )%>'
                                   NavigateUrl="~/"
                                   ToolTip="BalloonShop Logo"
                                   runat="server" />
```

Finally, I modified my .master.cs file by adding the following

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // a new declarative syntax <%# %> is the basis for using data binding
    Page.Header.DataBind();
    HeaderLink.DataBind();

}
```

and was able to display the logo.  If there is a better approach, I would definitely like to read it.